# Calling multiple stored procedures from stored procedure - sql while loop

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I often hear that while loops are as bad as cursors, which I did not believe to be true. ***Is it better from a performance standpoint to call multiple stored procedures from C#, or allow a stored procedure to parse XML data and call procedures in a looping fashion? Is there a better way to call an unknown number of stored procedures in SQL than looping?***

*Let me explain*

I have to design and implement a vendor messaging system. There is a third party company sending along XML messages to the recipient that originated from the sender. My company might be the sender or the recipient at any given time.

I have come up with a design that uses a SQL while loop to run stored procedures, but I'm worried that it might not perform well when faced with a large number of loops.

The basic idea is:
Sender --> third party (message system) --> receiver

My problem may occur when my company is the receiver:

1. Sender sends message to third party company
2. Third party company sends message to my company
3. WCF Service receives request from third party company
4. A stored procedure is called, passing the xml of the message received to be parsed
5. This stored procedure parses xml and finds messages in the XML
6. While loop goes through each message and calls a stored procedure to update information, passing the ID of the instance of the message.

The message XML is something like this:

```
<envelope>
    <to></to>
    <from></from>
    ...
    <messages>
       <message>
           <id></id>
           ...
           <params>
               <param>
                   <Name></Name>
                   <Value></Value>
               <param>
               ...
           </params>
       </message>
       ...
    </messages>
</envelope>
```

I can receive or send one or more messages in each transmission of XML. There could potentially be multiple messages received at once. A requirement of the third party company which handles sending and receiving the XML is that we always respond with Success or Fail. We have a 60 second timeout window to respond. Due to these limitations, I am naturally afraid that I won't be able to do all the processing I need to do in the time limit, causing a timeout.

So if I find message 1, 2 and 3 in one transmission, I would have to run stored procedure 1, 2 and 3. I have a temp table filled with message ID and stored procedure to run.

So the While loop would be basically (didn't check validity of this part, just free-handed it as I don't have the SP handy)

```
While select count(*) from #temptable > 0
begin
    select top 1 @idMessage = idMessage, @spToRun = spToRun from #temptable
    exec @spToRun @idMessage

    delete from #temptable where idMessage = @idMessage
    select @idMessage = null, @spToRun = null
end
```

I'm afraid to put this into production and then find out it runs far, far too slowly. Does anyone have advice?

Comment: Your issue is #6.  You have a stored procedure that is not set-based.  So you need to rework that procedure.....or do the (crappy) looping like you are doing.  Another idea is to span multiple threads/tasks in C# and send them in one at a time that way.  Look for "c# parallel foreach".....but keep in mind, if your data could overlap you could get race issues.

Comment: out of curiosity, is there a way to call stored procedures in SQL in a set-based fashion?

Comment: send in xml  and shred it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice is to go ahead and use C# to parse the xml and to call sprocs as needed from the dotnet side (as long as you keep the sql short and sweet). Obviously I am not completely familiar with your situation but from my experience its difficult to debug sql stored procs especially when they are heavy in logic/processing like it sounds like you are doing, even if you are using cursors/loops. Control is more granular from an environment like c# where you can put breakpoints, watch the value of variables (or in your case xml nodes) in memory as you step through your processing, and catch a wider variety of errors which can be very helpful when receiving files from a third party. Also while you might think sql to be just as good at performing as middleware as dot net, it is not middleware, it usually best serves you on the back end. Often in many organizations the sql server will have enough to do on the back end side and furthermore, in future, you may find your sql server overburdened if you find you have been asking too much of it and it will start acting weird on you. Lastly, as far as performance, I believe the benefits outweigh the extra trip time which should be alleviated anyways if you keep the sql simple and compiled as stored procs, and if you put it on a production server you should have ample memory. At the very least, if I had to for performance reasons, I would strike a balance with a bias to C#/dotnet and rely on sql server to do as little processing as possible.

Comment: Thanks - that's what I was looking for. I am more comfortable handling errors and divvying out tasks from C# than I am raising errors in SQL. My plan was to use output parameters (XML or varchar type) and process the output from C#, but after thinking more on WHY I was planning on doing that I realized I should just do it all from C#.

Answer (score 0):

Up to 1 MB of xml, I wouldn't blink twice about shredding it in the stored procedure.  (You don't say how many rows you have in the xml).

You will get MUCH better performance than sending in row by row.

If you have over 1 MB, consider a goldie-locks approach.  Do not send it in one-by-one, do not send it in "everything", but have an external c# process that shreds the xml into smaller parts.  Ex:  A file with 100,500 rows, send in 10,000 at a time for 11 sends.

You can play with the numbers on the goldie-locks approach.

..

I would verify your xml in C#, then I would send it down to sql-server as what I call "perfectXml", and then shred it, perhaps into a #temp table, and insert from there.  Again, this is key, the xml should be "perfect" in the sense that you are not running checks and if and this or that statements on it in the tsql.

Row by Row By Agonizing Row is for the birds.